# Adding multiple videos to uicollectionview - objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I'm having problems adding multiple videos to a uicollectionview.
I can add multiple images to a uicollectionview, and they are displayed correctly.
However when I try to add multiple videos, only the last video added will play.

// Select image/ video from phone gallery

```
- (void)chooseExistingImagesButton:(id)sender {

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeVideo, (NSString*)kUTTypeImage, nil];
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Sorry, we cannot detect a camera on this device." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
}

[imageCollectionView reloadData];
[videoCollectionView reloadData]; }

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[self targetImageArray];
[self targetVideoArray];

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    NSString *selectedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [targetImageArray addObject:selectedImage];
    [targetImageArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
}
else if (([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo]) || ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])) {
    NSString *moviePath = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    [targetVideoArray addObject:moviePath];
    [targetVideoArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
}

[imageCollectionView reloadData];
[videoCollectionView reloadData];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{NSLog(@"Finished Picking Image or Video");}]; }

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{NSLog(@"Image picker view dismissed");}]; }
```

// Load the collectionview

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1; }

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (collectionView.tag == ImageCell) {
    return [targetImageArray count];
}
if (collectionView.tag == VideoCell) {
    return [targetVideoArray count];
}
return 0; }

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (collectionView.tag == VideoCell) {
    static NSString *videoCellIdentifier = @"VideoCell";
    TargetVideoCell *videoCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:videoCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    movieUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [targetVideoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:movieUrl options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[generator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) actualTime:nil error:nil]];

    videoCell.targetMovieView.image = image;

    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:videoCell.targetMovieView.frame];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];

    return videoCell;
}


if (collectionView.tag == ImageCell) {
    static NSString *imageCellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
    TargetImageCell *imageCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:imageCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    imageCell.targetImageView.image = [targetImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return imageCell;
}

return 0; }
```

// Play video

```
- (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender {
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playMovieFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer]; }

- (void)playMovieFinished:(NSNotification *)theNotification {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
[moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
moviePlayer = nil;
[self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated]; }
```

Comment: `moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];` That seems to be the culprit. Only the "last" one has the `moviePlayer`. While when you put images, the cell has its own property to display the image. Also, why is your question tagged with `iPad` and `CoreData`?

Comment: Thanks for your response, i'm saving both the image and video arrays to CoreData, for an iPad app. First time posting here, thought if you add more tags, it would reach out to a few more people :)

Comment: The issue is that your issue is not proper to iPad (it could be on iPhone too), and is not related to CoreData (since you didn't even put a line of CoreData). They are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

On every cellForRow you init your movie player again. **moviePlayer** - this is property of your class.

**Solution:**

1. every cell must has own movie player.

   videoCell.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];
   [videoCell.moviePlayer.view setFrame:videoCell.targetMovieView.bounds];
2. has one movie player and catching event of button tapping

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated the code above, but i cant get the videos to play now. (not for the lack of trying) 

I'm getting errors such as:
    - no visible @interface for declares the selector dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated


    - Attempt to present <MPMoviePlayerViewController:> on <MPMoviePlayerViewController:> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Ive also been able to get the player to load, but it loads a blank screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help, got it working:

    - (void)playVideo:(id)sender {    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];
    
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES]; }

Comment: - (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
    
    if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    } }